# Ads quality for JavaScript generated landing pages

Tags: google-ads-api

I want to start AdWords campaign, where the ads will redirect to the landing page.

The landing page is generated by JavaScript.
It's a kind of single page app, where body is initially empty and after few moments it gets filled with content from JavaScript.

I know that the quality of the ads is determined also by landing page content.

My question is does it matter for add quality if the landing page is generated by JavaScript?